# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can not understand why this warning is appearing
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of .

This in my code here.

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';



const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/"><NavLink to="/" className="nav-link3">Restaurant-App</NavLink></Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#features" ><NavLink to="/" className="nav-link3">Home</NavLink></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing" ><NavLink to="/list" className="nav-link3">List</NavLink></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features"><NavLink to="/create" className="nav-link3">Create</NavLink></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing"><NavLink to="/search" className="nav-link3">Search</NavLink></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing" ><NavLink to="/update" className="nav-link3">Update</NavLink></Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>

  )

}

export default Navigation
```

I used react-router-dom": "^6.6.2

Comment: You're passing a `NavLink` from 'react-router-dom' which is a `a` element, to a `Nav.Link` from 'react-bootstrap' which is also a `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering a `NavLink` component (*an anchor tag*) inside a `Nav.Link` component (*also an anchor tag*). You are also specifying two different link targets for each. You can specify that the `Nav.Link` component ***really*** render a `NavLink` component by passing the `NavLink` to the `Nav.Link` component's `as` prop. I'll assume you are trying to navigate to the specific pages and hash link, so these two targets will be merged.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand as={NavLink} to="/" className="nav-link3">
          Restaurant-App
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/#features" className="nav-link3">
              Home
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/list#pricing" className="nav-link3">
              List
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/create#features" className="nav-link3">
              Create
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/search#pricing" className="nav-link3">
              Search
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/update#pricing" className="nav-link3">
              Update
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```