# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. React-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i cannot find any solutions of this error `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.`  on **REACT-ROTER-DOM v6**.

some of the other questions and answer came from `react-bootstrap` but not using `react-router-dom v6++`

i already followed these two but it still the same error i got

[react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206405/react-dom-development-js86-warning-validatedomnesting-a-cannot-appear)
[Warning: validateDOMNesting(…): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409964/warning-validatedomnesting-a-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant-of-a).

in my code i am using two `LINK` link inside of link on react-router-dom v6

Here is my code .

```
 <ul className="flex text-white text-xl items-center gap-10">
          <li className="cursor-pointer">
                    <Link to="/" className=" text-green-700 hover:text-green-500 hover:border-b-4 border-green-400">Home</Link>
          </li>
           <li className="cursor-pointer dropdown">
                    <Link to="/"  className="dropbtn text-green-700 hover:text-green-500 hover:border-b-4 border-green-400">
                        <span>Fitness</span>
                       <ul className="dropdown-content flex-col gap-3 p-2 text-green-900">
                          <li className="text-lg hover:text-green-500">
                            <Link  to='/bobo' role='link'>Beginners</Link>
                         </li>
                       </ul>
                  </Link>
         </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Link` inside `Link`? That is, are you sure that the whole `ul` must be treated as a part of an outer `Link`?

Comment: yes i want to use LINK inside of LINK i don't know how to fix that

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link

Comment: Nesting links inside links is invalid HTML and semantically doesn't make any sense. What is the use case here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the parent LINK is when they click it. it shows all of the list LINK child he have. meanwhile the child LINK is optional show when they click it redirect to their path

Comment: But why would parent `Link` contain all child `Link`s and not only their common header?

Comment: oh you right and you have point, maybe i will make optional title their parent link? since i don't need to show all their list